# Windows Mobile Web Services - works while tethered, not while using cell data network

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services, windows-mobile

I've written an ASP.NET web service that I would like a .NET 3.x application running under Windows Mobile 6.1 to communicate with.

When the phone is connected to a desktop via USB/ActiveSync it can communicate with the web service flawlessly.

When I place the phone on the cell network (unplug the USB cable) it is not able to communicate with the web service.  I get a System.Net.WebException -> Unable to connect to remote server.  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException -> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

When I attempt to browse to the ASMX page via the mobile browser (Opera), while on the cell network, it connects and renders the description page perfectly.

Any ideas?

Comment: I know my provider (Verizon Wireless) has two data plans, one of which basically only allows conenctions through port 80 - perhaps you have to "hard code" to that port since Opera has no trouble?

Comment: Thanks David, but this is not an issue.  The application also communicates with a custom-developed TCP server on 3 different TCP ports without a problem (on the cell network).

Comment: Are you using a named domain to access the WebService, or are you connecting via an IP address?

Comment: Can you please accept your answer so this question doesn't show up on the "unanswered" list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this before seeing GenericTypeTea's comment - but good job GTT, right on the money.

Apparently when you use the GUI in VS to add a web reference it converts the domain address into an IP address.  How ridiculous.

Anyhow.. solved.